# How Do I Animate the Opacity for the Listbox item Highlighter?

Tags: xaml

[The Example Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zt7vl.jpg)

How do I make the opacity of the listbox highlighter animated? I'm trying to animate this portion here with a fade in and fade out effect:

```
RadialGradientBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Opacity="0.15"
```

Comment: What you have tried so far? Add a [Minimal, Complete and Verfiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of it.

Comment: click on the link called "the example code" above. I think I got this wrong but am unsure: Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RadialGradientBrush.Opacity)"

Comment: Feel free to add the code right in the question as well, using the `code` block.

Comment: when I copy and paste from xaml, it gives me an error about wrong format. even if I highlight it and press the code button. that's why I used an image instead.

Comment: Here is a pastiebin link so things can be highlighted and copy and pasted and stuff: https://www.pastiebin.com/5a035b746c651

Comment: My mistake. Didn't mean to post those values. Here are the real values but it's still not working:

<code>BeginTime="0:0:0" From="0.05" To="0.85" Duration="0:0:0.5" AutoReverse="True"</code>

Comment: Helloooooooooo? Well can anybody tell me how they would do it themselves by doing it within their listbox???